# Use ansible variable in replace string for regex_replace

Tags: ansible

I want to generate a new list from `files` by prepending `/auto` and appending `_sw_table` to each element. While I can do this by explicitly mentioning the new strings as args to `regex_replace` in `map`, I want to achieve the same using variables. The following works:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      my_lst: []
      top_dir: /auto
      extra: sw_table
      files: ['/etc/passwd', '/etc/group']

  - set_fact:
      my_lst: "{{ files | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '/auto\\1_sw_table') | list }}"

  - debug: var=my_lst
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, ./test.yaml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_lst": [
        "/auto/etc/passwd_sw_table", 
        "/auto/etc/group_sw_table"
    ]
}
```

How can I use the variables `top_dir` and `extra` in the call to `map` to get the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string concatenation in Jinja2:

```
  - set_fact:
      my_lst: "{{ files | map('regex_replace', '(^.*$)', top_dir + '\\1' + extra) | list }}"
```

Do take note of the updated regex pattern that I used. I had different results to your output above, and needed to update the pattern.